# I have two JSON files. One JSON file is updated as each cycle and values are changed. I want to save each value at each cycle on my second JSON

Tags: python, json, dictionary, counter

X values are being taken from a Y.JSON file. The Y file could change in values depending. I want the X file to save all values without overwriting the previous saved value.

```
# Initialize new dictionary/JSON for X
X = dict ()
with open('X.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(X))
```

Comment: If you just want to append data to an existing file, change the `open` from 'w' to 'a'. If you are talking about *updating* keys in the existing file, then you have to read the file in and update it, there's no way to edit in-place. (barring calling an editor sub-process).

Comment: How do you do that? read the file and then update it ? Also, let say the Y jason file is being updated in a loop, In each iteration it saves a different value. I want the X file to save all the values for all iterations

Comment: I'm still not exactly sure what the problem-definition is, you talk about the Y file, but the code is opening an X file. But it sounds like there is only one file, and two processes that are writing to it - possibly the second process is *both* reading, and writing the file, modifying the data before writing. Additionally, given that it's JSON values, I'm assuming you're trying to update keys in the file. Can you clarify the question some?

Comment: Assuming my previous comment is correct, it sounds like you're really trying to emulate a database. :) How much control do you have over either process? It might be worth looking at a lightweight DB, like `SQLite`. Alternately - if the keys/data are all the same *length* - you could do something like the Python `seek()`, which allows you to position the file pointer and write at that location. That's messy, and I don't suggest it (okay, I did just suggest it - I don't *recommend* it). Or maybe use inter-process communication, and only *one* process actually writes the file.

Comment: To be more specific, i have a dictionary with signals where I am deciding on the keywords, then filtering those signals, and only have three different values written and saved in my X json file. So the Y JSON file is the one that has all the PCM signals that can be updated. I am taking from that Y JSON file three signals and make sure that the counter for those signals is working and increasing with each iteration

Comment: Still not entirely clear on the flow, sorry. But it sounds like you have two processes, *and* two files, one file is a target-file that both processes write to, and one file is a source-file that only "your" process is reading. Maybe do a pseudo-code description of what's going on (and call the files "target.json" and "source.json"), in the main question body? (instead of extending the comments). In any case, I suspect my earlier suggestion of either inter-process comm, or a database, still holds.

Comment: I made another post where I hope I made it clearer. please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68229433/rolling-counter-check-in-python

Answer (score 0):

If these cycles do not represent any value/meaning which you'd like to include in the filename, you could try to time encode the filenames. In this way, you end up with file names that include the time the files were saved at.

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
time = now.strftime("%y%m%d%M%S") # choose any format you like
filename = time+'_X.json'

X = dict ()
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(X))
```

For example, if files are being created every 4 seconds gives the following filenames:

```
2106265848_X.json
2106265852_X.json
2106265856_X.json
2106265900_X.json
2106265904_X.json
2106265908_X.json
2106265912_X.json
2106265916_X.json
2106265920_X.json
```

**However**, if the cycles (or whatever experiment you are doing) do matter I would strongly recommend to include it in the filed name.
e.g.

```
filename = f"{time}_X_c{cycle}.json"
```

To end up with something like this as results:

```
2106260547_X_c0.json
2106260551_X_c1.json
2106260555_X_c2.json
2106260559_X_c3.json
2106260603_X_c4.json
```

Comment: I don't think I completely understood the question but it is very sparse. This was my best shot. Hope it helps!

Comment: All values should be saved in the same JSON file. To be more specific, let say we have a counter, each iteration the value changes in the Y JSON file, meaning the new values over write the old ones, I want to have those values at each iteration all saved in another JSON file.